# How to plot multiple Y axes in plotly using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-python

I have a requirement to plot a graph which has multiple Y axes. I could plot single Y axis using pandas, plotly in Python3.7. All my data comes from CSV, please let me know how can I plot multiple Y axes in same graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Test.csv')
fig = px.line(df, x = 'XData', y = 'YData', title='Demo')
fig.show()
```